# Unexpected newlines in bash for loop

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am having a newline issue in my BASH code trying to loop the following:

```
bash-4.3$ vboxmanage list vms
  "node1" {280482b5-3913-4019-aa9a-383f1f3131a1}
  "test_default_1419033096698_75346" {9a2f7b6b-33d8-4997-9c35-9b86f3d183b6}
```

Knowing that, I get unexpected results below

```
for name in $(vboxmanage list vms); do
    echo "==> $name"
done

  ## Prints
  ==> "node1"
  ==> {280482b5-3913-4019-aa9a-383f1f3131a1}
  ==> "test_default_1419033096698_75346"
  ==> {9a2f7b6b-33d8-4997-9c35-9b86f3d183b6}
```

I would expect to get the following though?

```
  ==> "node1" {280482b5-3913-4019-aa9a-383f1f3131a1}
  ==> "test_default_1419033096698_75346" {9a2f7b6b-33d8-4997-9c35-9b86f3d183b6}
```

So I attempt to this instead and...

```
for name in "$(vboxmanage list vms)"; do
    echo "==> $name"
done

  ==> "node1" {280482b5-3913-4019-aa9a-383f1f3131a1}
  "test_default_1419033096698_75346" {9a2f7b6b-33d8-4997-9c35-9b86f3d183b6}
```

*The results are on one line as expected...*

What I am curious about is WHY the first example does this, I know well enough that multiple lines should be read with a `while loop`. I am more curious as to why it is doing this, I am not interested in implementing `for` as a solution.

Comment: This is [BashFAQ/001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf that is all line reading with `while` I am interested in `for` in this case.

Comment: [Don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: @DavidRavetti just caught that, it was supposed to be double quoted, I fixed the question

Comment: Why? word splitting + pathname expansion...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your loop is essentially this:

```
for name in "node1" {280482b5-3913-4019-aa9a-383f1f3131a1} "test_default_1419033096698_75346" {9a2f7b6b-33d8-4997-9c35-9b86f3d183b6}
do
    echo "$name"
done
```

That is, each of the separate words is being printed in a separate iteration of your loop.

As [the FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) will tell you, use a `while read` loop instead:

```
while read -r name
do
    echo "$name"
done < <(vboxmanage list vms)
```

As the FAQ also mentions, if you want to preserve leading and trailing whitespace, you should use `IFS= while read -r name`. This clears the value of the Input Field Separator, `IFS` for the duration of the command.